# Update Last Modified date for all documents in Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Is it possible to update last modified date = today() after every 6 month for all items in document library using designer workflow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than going with the SharePoint designer workflow, I would recommend going with the normal PowerShell or PnP PowerShell as this will be an automation job that should run once in every six months. Create a sample PowerShell script or PnP script and configure that script in the **windows task scheduler** which should run once in every six months.

To develop the script, you may refer the below PowerShell coding:

```
<#
Title: Set modified and created by details
Author: Alex Brassington
Category: Proof of Concept Script
Description
This script is to show how to read, modify and otherwise manipulate the created by and modified by details on documents.
This is to enable correction of incorrect data as part of migrations. It is also useful to enable testing of retention policies.
#>
 
#Add the SharePoint snapin
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ea SilentlyContinue
 
#set the web url and the list name to work upon
$url = "http://sharepoint/sites/cthub"
$listName = "Shared Documents"
$fileName = "FileName.xlsx"
 
#Get the appropriate list from the web
$web = get-SPWeb $url
$list = $web.lists[$listName]
 
#Get the file using the filename
$item = $list.Items | ? {$_.Name -eq $fileName}
 
#Print out current Created by and Created date
Write-Output ("item created by {0} on {1}" -f $item["Author"].tostring(), $item["Created"] )
 
#Print out current Created by and Created date
Write-Output ("item last modified by {0} on {1}" -f $item["Editor"].tostring(), ($item["Modified"] -f "dd-MM-yyyy"))
 
#Set the created by values
$userLogin = "ALEXB\AlexB"
$dateToStore = Get-Date "10/02/1984"
 
$user = Get-SPUser -Web $web | ? {$_.userlogin -eq $userLogin}
$userString = "{0};#{1}" -f $user.ID, $user.UserLogin.Tostring()
 
 
#Sets the created by field
$item["Author"] = $userString
$item["Created"] = $dateToStore
 
#Set the modified by values
$item["Editor"] = $userString
$item["Modified"] = $dateToStore
 
 
#Store changes without overwriting the existing Modified details.
$item.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
```

Reference:

[Changing Modified, and Created details in SharePoint](http://alexbrassington.com/2013/11/07/changing-modified-and-created-details-in-sharepoint/)

**PnP Sample:**

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing"
$ListName = "Branding"
$CreatedBy = "Salaudeen@crescent.com"
$ModifiedBy = "Salaudeen@crescent.com"
$Created = "2018-01-01T12:00:00-00:00"
$Modified = "2018-02-02T10:30:00-00:00"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
    
#Get all Files from the document library
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 2000 -Fields Author | Where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File"}
    
#Update document properties
$ListItems | ForEach-Object {
    Set-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $_.Id -Values @{"Created"=$Created; "Modified"=$Modified; "Author" = $CreatedBy; "Editor" = $ModifiedBy; } | Out-Null
    Write-host "Metadata Set to "$_.FieldValues.FileRef -f Green
    }
```

Reference:

[SharePoint Online: Update Created By / Modified By, Created At / Modified At Field Values using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/11/update-created-by-modified-by-created-at-modified-at-values-using-powershell.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to update last modified date as today() every 6 month for all items in document library by using designer workflow.

As a workaround, you could use PowerShell to achieve.

Reference:

[SharePoint Online: Update Created By / Modified By, Created At / Modified At Field Values using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/11/update-created-by-modified-by-created-at-modified-at-values-using-powershell.html)

Comment: with Azure job is it feasible?